# There's any way to know if a VB.NET application is being debugged?

Tags: debugging, vb.net-2010

I have an application developed on VB.NET2010 and I need to enable some objects only when is in debug mode.

The application can know when is being debugged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    ....
}
```

(Debugger belongs to the System.Diagnostics namespace)

Answer (score 2):

you can try to add these preprocessor lines in your script!

```
#If DEBUG Then
Console.WriteLine("Debug mode.")
#Else
Console.WriteLine("Release mode.")
#End If
```

You will get the result as per conditions.

Comment: This will not determine if the application is being debugged or not, rather it says if it was built with the Debug configuration or not.